# build_ext not found whilst installing google-cloud-vision with pip on windows

Tags: python, pip, google-cloud-vision

As the title says, I'm getting an error whilst installing Google Cloud Vision on a Windows 10 machine running Python 3.8.

I've added python to my PATH and have also installed Build Tools for Visual Studio Code (read somewhere that this might help - it didn't).

Below are the commands that I have tried:
`pip install google-cloud-vision`
`pip install google-cloud-vision --ignore-installed`

The error I'm getting is:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-install-n38ejusk\\grpcio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-install-n38ejusk\\grpcio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-record-tnd8s2qv\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-n38ejusk\grpcio\
    Complete output (62 lines):
    Found cython-generated files...
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_project_metadata
    creating python_build
    creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_auth.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_channel.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_common.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_compression.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_grpcio_metadata.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_interceptor.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_plugin_wrapping.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_server.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc
    creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\beta
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\implementations.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\beta
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\interfaces.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\beta
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\beta
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\_client_adaptations.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\beta
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\_metadata.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\beta
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\_server_adaptations.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\beta
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\beta\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\beta
    creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\experimental
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\gevent.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\experimental
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\session_cache.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\experimental
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\experimental\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\experimental
    creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework
    creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\_cython
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_cython\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\_cython
    creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\common
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\common\cardinality.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\common
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\common\style.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\common
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\common\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\common
    creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\abandonment.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\callable_util.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\future.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\logging_pool.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\stream.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\stream_util.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\foundation\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\foundation
    creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces
    creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\base
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\base\base.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\base
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\base\utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\base
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\base\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\base
    creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\face
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\face\face.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\face
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\face\utilities.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\face
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\framework\interfaces\face\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\framework\interfaces\face
    creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\_cython\_cygrpc
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_cython\_cygrpc\__init__.py -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\_cython\_cygrpc
    creating python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\_cython\_credentials
    copying src\python\grpcio\grpc\_cython\_credentials\roots.pem -> python_build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\grpc\_cython\_credentials
    running build_ext
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\administrator\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-install-n38ejusk\\grpcio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\pip-install-n38ejusk\\grpcio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-record-tnd8s2qv\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20604

Comment: I have the same problem with Python v. 3.9

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, we are not pre-compiling for 3.8 yet. If you can use Python 3.6 or 3.7, the problem should go away. https://pypi.org/project/grpcio/#files

I'm not recommending investigate the compilation of grpcio on Windows, because it is not easy to get it right.

-lidizheng

Comment: Python 3.8 has been out for a while now, and many popular google apps require grpcio (including most google cloud services). If GRPCIO doesn't support Python 3.8, then effectively, Google Cloud services cannot run on Python 3.8 on a Windows dev environment. Would be nice if the Google Cloud documentation mentioned this somewhere.